# Получить все значения div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начну с примера:

```
<div class='ff'>Пример1</div><div class='ff'>Пример2</div><div class='ff'>Пример3</div>
```

Мне нужно со всех классов вытянуть значение (Пример1/Пример2/Пример3). Вроде элементарное задание, а уже пару часов на него убил, и не могу выполнить.

ps  сильно ногами не пинайте)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arrayOfDiv = $(".ff");
for(var i in arrayOfDiv)
    console.log(arrayOfDiv[i].innerHTML);
```